# Administrator URL '&' changed to '&amp;'

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5, php-5.3

I'm working on my **localhost** and on a system where all administrator URL's which contain a `&`, `&` is changed to `&amp;` and that in turn breaks the system.

What setting is doing this? What do I need to disable? My localhost is PHP 5.3. I have to mention that other Joomla system's are working perfectly fine and the `&` in the url are not converted to `&amp;`.

Comment: Turning DEBUG on rectifies the situation temporarily, but this is not a fix.

Comment: Where do you see `&` instead of `&amp;`? It should indeed be the latter in the HTML/XHTML source.

Comment: In the URL itself, though it says `&` only in the physical page source. It gets converted after the click.

Comment: Where do you see `&` instead of `&amp;`?

Comment: Removed answer as on the wrong track completely, mis-read the question. My mistake. Sounds like there's some encoding going on somewhere, is the link using htmlspecialchars($item->title); or something similar? Afraid I can't help if it's that Joomla specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting that can do this in Joomla 2.5 (as far as I know).

The only think capable of doing such a thing would have to be a system plugin that will re-encode the URLs.

So my first idea would be to check all the System plugins that may be URL related (like SEF things, or redirect plugins or some routing plug in and so on).

If that fails try to disable all System plugins and see if that fixes the issue.

Another way to test is to get a new fresh Joomla install and add one by one the components that you have on the broken install.

**PS:** Turns out it was a custom system plugin. (see comments)

Comment: You're right, it was a custom plugin incorporated in the system. I disabled it and the behaviour vanished.